# getting file not found error while running in web Application, and same thing works fine in standalone java program

Tags: java

I want to run one java file from other java file in web Application.
I run the same code in standalone application but in web its giving error.
name.java file is in the same package only.

```
public runMethod(){
          runProcess("javac -cp src src/com/kj/somaiya/name.java");
          runProcess("java -cp src com/kj/somaiya/name hj hu");
}

public  void runProcess(String command) throws Exception {
        Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        pro.waitFor();
        System.out.println(command + " exitValue() " + pro.exitValue());
}
```

Comment: servlet run in different context, rights, system path etc

Comment: how I will get the right path?